# React Router Change transitionName on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have added CSSTransitionsGroup to my React-Router to create page transitions. Now, I want to have different transitions, based on which link I click.
For example: I always want to use 'fade', except for when I click on the 'Work' button, then I want to use 'slideLeft'.
I am using React-Router 4, and the normal React Animation Add-Ons from https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html.

My App component with my Router and Transitions look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup' // ES6
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';

import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory();

import Home from '../containers/Home';
import Work from '../containers/Work';
import BTS from '../containers/BTS';
import SinglePage from '../containers/SinglePage';
import NotFound from '../containers/NotFound';
import store from '../store';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <Route render={({ location }) => (
            <CSSTransitionGroup
              transitionName="fade"
              transitionEnterTimeout={500}
              transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
              <Switch key={location.key} location={location}>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/work" component={Work}/>
                <Route exact path="/behind-the-scenes" component={BTS}/>
                <Route path="/about" component={SinglePage}/>
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
              </Switch>
            </CSSTransitionGroup>
          )}/>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

And my Home component just have 3 simple buttons:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Home extends Component{

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="home page">
        <main>
              <ul>
                <li><Link to="/work">Work</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/behind-the-scenes">behind the scenes</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/3eBtn">3e Btn</Link></li>
              </ul>
        </main>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So It always uses Fade, because I called `transitionName="fade"`, but I want to call 'SlideLeft' when I click the '/work' Link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put the Condition on value of `transitionName`, when the location will be `work` then assign the `SlideLeft` otherwise `fade`.

```
<CSSTransitionGroup 
    transitionName={location.pathName == "work" ? "SlideLeft" : "fade"}
```

Comment: Hmm, this is a smart way. But if I, for example, go from my Menu to the 'Work' link, I want it to fade. It only has to do other transitions when I click specific buttons. Is this possible?

Comment: not sure about this, but you can try by putting that conditions :)